# Using a changeable length number and left function to exclude results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking to exclude phone numbers from a list based on their prefix.  Some countries have longer or shorter prefixed than others.  The UK for Example +44, France +33, Vatican city +379, Gibraltar +350

I would like to exclude results that are not in a list, is it possible?

I am thinking it may be possible with something like:

```
select *
from tblPrankCalls
where LEFT(LEN(listitem), country_prefix) not in ('+33', '+379')
```

Assuming tblPrankCalls includes the 4 results above, I'd like to see France +44 and Gibraltar +350 returned.

I should say im not sure if it is possible, because the criteria might lead to contradictory results (still scratching my head about thatone).  Is it possible?  Is there another good course of action to exclude (or include) data in this situation?

Note: I can't use RIGHT as the phone number length will also change.

Edit:  In real life I will be using more than 2 results- say excluding 30 results at a time.

I also don't believe this to be a duplicate of this:

[Phone number lookups using incoming numbers of varying lengths, with or without prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064354/phone-number-lookups-using-incoming-numbers-of-varying-lengths-with-or-without)

Comment: You want to exclude `+33` and `+379` right ?

Comment: Is there a pattern to exclude the country codes?

Comment: in reality I'd like to exclude all on a continent, say europe for example, unfortunately there's no concrete discrenable pattern           https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Europe

Comment: you mean that you want to exclude more than 2 phone number ?

Comment: @tompreston   like exclude Africa phone numbers ?

Comment: @tompreston You can add a field "local" to your phone table :country_prefix=+44 and local = 'Europe'. then :  `select * from tblprankcalls where local <>'Europe'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a general outline of one way to approach this problem. Without sample tables, structures, and data, I can’t provide relevant sample code.

Step 1: Create a table (permanent, temp, whatever) containin the relevant prefixes. Determine if this is an “include all” or exclude all” list. Base this on the fact that country prefix codes *may* change over time.

Step 2: How do you identify the Prefix? If not the firxt N characters, then it must be some form of delimiter, like +33-123, or +379-456? Come up with an algorithm to generate (extract) this value.

Step 3: Using the above algorithm, build a means of reliably extracting the prefix code from however you have “full” phone codes stored in your source table. Ideally, this is its own column in the table; less ideally, you wire your extraction code into a computed column on the table; least optimally, you recalculate it every time you run this query. Net result: one value per row in your source table.

Step 4: Use an appropriate tactic (several listed below), join the two tables: “TheList”, the source data table, and “InclusionList/ExclusionList”, of desired/undesired prefixes with table of established prefixes). Several ways to do this:

--  Get all valid

```
…from TheList tl inner join InclusionList il on il.CountryPrefix = tl.CountryPrefix

…from TheList where CountryPrefix in (select CountryPrefix from InclusionList)

…from TheList tl where exists (select CountryPrefix from InclusionList where CountryPrefix = tl.CountryPrefix)
```

--  Exlude invalid

```
…from TheList tl left outer join ExclusionList el on el.CountryPrefix = tl.CountryPrefix where el.CountryPrefix is not null

…from TheList where CountryPrefix not in (select CountryPrefix from ExclusionList)

…from TheList tl where not exists (select CountryPrefix from ExclusionList where CountryPrefix = tl.CountryPrefix)
```